# Asp.net session timeouts

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, windows-authentication

Can anyone tell me why the session clears itself automatically after a certain amount of time in my application?

I use the following line to create a session variable to pass data between classes:

string data = TextBox.Text
Session["Data"] = data;

After around 10 - 15 minutes i refresh the page to find that the session cache has been cleared and my application collapses on itself.

Is there a way to extend the session time in web.config?

Im not fully aware of how powerful Session's can be so any help would be great guys thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in your `web.config` file and see the `sessionState` section:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <sessionState timeout="30"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I have changed it to `30` to extend the `Sessions` life for an additional 15minutes.  You can change this to suit your requirements.

Comment: It's been a while, but I think the application pool can also cause this. Just something else to check perhaps.

Comment: @MikeC. you are right. If Inproc session storage is used, any restart of the app domain (pool recycling, edit in web.config, ...) will clear the session

Comment: @JBL can you perhaps elaborate on what inproc session storage is?

Comment: @user2500842 - it just stores the session state in memory on the server.  I believe jbl and Mike are trying to say if the Application Pool is recycled the session will be cleared, which is true - however you are trying to adjust the timeout which is what my answer provides.